# create user defined function in R with a list not only one inputs

Tags: r, function

I want to create functions that I can test with multiple inputs such as a list of numbers below is my code. I want to test several inputs not only but I do not how to do the same in the function argument.

```
grads<-function((for (X in 0:100)))
  
if (x<=50){
  "Fail"
}else if (x<=70){
  "Good"
  
}else if (x<=80){
  "V Good"
} else {
  "Execellent"
}

grads(95,60,77,33)
```

this is error that I got

```
Error in grads(95, 60, 77, 33) : unused arguments (60, 77, 33)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
grads <- function(x) {
     data.table::fcase(x <= 50, "Fail",
                       x <= 70, "Good",
                       x <= 80, "Very Good",
                       default = "Excellent")
}
```

-testing

```
grads(c(95,60,77,33))
[1] "Excellent" "Good"      "Very Good" "Fail"
```

---

Or using `findInterval` from `base R`

```
grads <- function(x)  {
      c("Fail", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")[findInterval(x,
       c(0, 50, 70, 80, 100))]
}
grads(c(95,60,77,33))
[1] "Excellent" "Good"      "Very Good" "Fail"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use vectorized functions to work with more than one value.

Here are some options.

1. Nested `ifelse`.

```
grads<- function(x) {
  ifelse(x <= 50, "Fail", 
         ifelse(x <= 70, "Good", 
                ifelse(x <= 80, "Very Good", "Excellent")))
}

grads(c(95,60,77,33))
#[1] "Excellent" "Good"      "Very Good" "Fail"
```

2. `case_when` from `dplyr` which is more readable for nested conditions

```
grads<- function(x) {
  dplyr::case_when(x <= 50 ~ "Fail", 
                   x <= 70 ~ "Good", 
                   x <= 80 ~ "Very Good",
                   TRUE ~ "Excellent")
}
grads(c(95,60,77,33))
```

3. `cut` which is scalable.

```
grads<- function(x) {
  cut(x, c(0, 50, 70, 80, 100), c("Fail", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"))
}
grads(c(95,60,77,33))
```